# ASM x86 - Shift Left

Tags: assembly, shift

I am running into a fairly simple problem (I think)...
Here is my code:

```
    mov eax, 0b
    mov bl, 0b
    mov dl, BYTE PTR[esp + 4 + 3]

LOOP1:
    mov cl, dl// byte 1
    shl cl, bl
```

I am getting an improper operand type when I call shl... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

The SHL operator only allows a shift by 1,  or a shift by the contents of the CL register.

Perhaps you intended:

```
  SHL   BL, CL
```

to shift the BL register by the amount in CL.

Comment: You can shift by greater than 1, without using the CL register, if you specify .286 at the top of your file.  The CL restriction is an 8086 restriction, which is the default if nothing else is specified.

Comment: Hmm, the assembly code I have written contains some of these non-unit constant shifts.  Wonder why I didn't remember this when I wrote the answer.  Thanks for the correction!